# Replace int with date in DataFrame column

Tags: python, replace, formatting

I have a DataFrame called `user_logs` with `msno` as key

```
 msno  date  num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq  total_secs

rxIP2f2aN0rYNp+toI0Obt/N/FYQX8hcO1fTmmy2h34=  20150513  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  280.335
rxIP2f2aN0rYNp+toI0Obt/N/FYQX8hcO1fTmmy2h34=  20150709  9  1  0  0  0  1  1  280.335
yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150105  3  3  0  0  0  1  1  280.335
yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150306  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  280.335
yxiEWwE9VR5utpUecLxVdQ5B7NysUPfrNtGINaM2zA8=  20150501  3  0  0  0  38  38  9649.029
```

The `date` column is in int and I would like to have it as a `datetime` format but I'm completely stuck. I only got as fare as to create a new variable where I actually succedded in formatting into dates:

```
Dates = pd.DataFrame([datetime.strptime(format(d, '.0f'), '%Y%m%d') for d in user_logs.loc[: , 'date']])
```

But I have a feeling that using `DataFrame.replace` might be usefull?

Comment: There is attribute in read_table when you read from file to create dataframe called parse_dates. Try to set it to True. It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if create `DataFrame` from file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Another solution is [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
user_logs['date'] = pd.to_datetime(user_logs['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(20150513)
```

will convert this timestamp to a datetime object.